# As she gathered or as she was gathering

Tags: simple-past

I was studying for the ACT ,and I encountered a question.
There is a sentence:

- *Donna was surprised at my suggestion, but quickly began sharing my unbridled enthusiasm as she ___ the appropriate chemicals and concoctions that would soon transform me.*

The question asks about what comes in place of the space (using the verb **gather**).

I Thought it should be are “... she was gathering...”.

However, the answer given is  “... she gathered...” Can someone please explain why it is past simple and not past continuous?

Comment: As usual, it's a matter of opinion. Both are grammatical, but the progressive would indicate that that the gathering was the important activity, when it was actually background for the really important thing, which was still in the future for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> As usual, it's a matter of opinion. Both are grammatical, but the progressive would indicate that that the gathering was the important activity, when it was actually background for the really important thing, which was still in the future for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

As she was gathering is less applicable, because that would show another meaning.

Think about the part of the sentence this way: as she was gathering= because she was gathering.

Otherwise, both are perfectly fine.

Comment: The 'because' reading is not the default option and is patently not intended here.

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't be past continuous because nothing happened when she was gathering the chemicals. Normally when using past continuous you explain what was happening after the verb. In this case it just wouldn't make sense because you are talking about something that was already stated prior to the verb.

I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: So you are saying is that to use past continuous there has to be an interruption. But since there is no interruption we should use past simple. But I couldn’t understand why there isn’t an interruption. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @AtillaÇolak There is no interruption because the sharing of the enthusiasm happens in parallel to the gathering of the chemicals. If Donna was drinking wine rather than sharing enthusiasm she would be drinking "while she was gathering chemicals" because she would have to stop gathering every time she lifted the glass. Having said that there's only a 1 in 2 chance that I would have answered the question 'correctly' and I am a native speaker. From other questions on EL&U this seems to be a common thing with ACT questions.